# Spinner for REST API using pure JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I am calling rest API and trying to use spinner before it loads result.

It's written in pure JS so I am not able to find the right solution for it.

Here is my code. I need the preloader to load until the result is displayed. for example, before `no result found` i want some spinner. I have spinner coded though but I need to display it until the script runs. a console.log could work for me, I can replace the spinner script there.

Thank you

```js
function callREST() {
  const app = document.getElementById('root');

  while (app.firstChild) {
    app.removeChild(app.firstChild);
  }

  var inputForm = document.getElementById('zip');
  var code = inputForm.value;

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'Path to API URL' + code, true);

  request.onload = function() {

    // Begin accessing JSON data here
    var responseData = JSON.parse(this.response);
    var data = responseData.Agents.Agent;

    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {

      var zip = responseData.Agents['@ZipCode'];

      if (typeof data == 'undefined' || zip != code) {
        const noData = document.createElement('div');
        noData.setAttribute('class', 'container text-center font-weight-bold pt-3');
        noData.textContent = 'No agent available.';
        app.appendChild(noData);
      } else if (zip === code) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var agent = data[i];

          const card = document.createElement('div');
          card.setAttribute('class', 'result');

        };
      }

    } else {
      const errorMessage = document.createElement('div');
      errorMessage.textContent = "Something is not right!";
      app.appendChild(errorMessage);
    }
  }


  request.send();
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <main id="main">
    <form action="#" class="question-form">
      <h1>Enter your zip code</h1>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
        <input type="text" id="zip" class="form-control" oninput="zipData()">
      </div>
      <div class="button-holder">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="callREST()">Search</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </main>
  <div id="loader" class="loading-overlay">
    <img src="images/spinner.svg" alt="image description">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check `request.readyState === 4` which means it's done, then do your stuff (hide the preloader)  when that condition is true.

Comment: @I.R.R. but I do i show the preloader until the script is running?

Comment: You can show your preloader in an if block where `request.readyState === 0` which means request not sent yet (or even before that, like onclick or something). Here's the full referrence: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState

Comment: @I.R.R. okay, i will check that. i have updated the question as well where I added HTML snippet as well. so the preloader should be visible once the `search` button is clicked until any result or message is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So three things:

1. Set the preloader to `display:none` from the get go. I set it inline here.
2. Set the preloader to `diplay: block` when `callREST()` is executed. Make it the first thing after the variable declarations.
3. Set the preloader back to `display:none` after `request.readyState === 4` (and/or whatever other condition you want to check for)

Here we go:

```js
function callREST() {
  const app = document.getElementById('root'),
        preloader = document.getElementById('loader');

  preloader.setAttribute('style', 'display:block');

  while (app.firstChild) {
    app.removeChild(app.firstChild);
  }

  var inputForm = document.getElementById('zip');
  var code = inputForm.value;

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'Path to API URL' + code, true);

  request.onload = function() {

    // Begin accessing JSON data here
    var responseData = JSON.parse(this.response);
    var data = responseData.Agents.Agent;

    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {

      var zip = responseData.Agents['@ZipCode'];

      if (typeof data == 'undefined' || zip != code) {
        const noData = document.createElement('div');
        noData.setAttribute('class', 'container text-center font-weight-bold pt-3');
        noData.textContent = 'No agent available.';
        app.appendChild(noData);
      } else if (zip === code) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var agent = data[i];

          const card = document.createElement('div');
          card.setAttribute('class', 'result');

        };
      }

    } else {
      const errorMessage = document.createElement('div');
      errorMessage.textContent = "Something is not right!";
      app.appendChild(errorMessage);
    }
  }


  request.send();

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {

      if (request.readyState === 4) {
          preloader.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <main id="main">
    <form action="#" class="question-form">
      <h1>Enter your zip code</h1>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
        <input type="text" id="zip" class="form-control" oninput="zipData()">
      </div>
      <div class="button-holder">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="callREST()">Search</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </main>
  <div id="loader" class="loading-overlay" style="display:none;">
    <img src="images/spinner.svg" alt="image description">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: everything worked but it didn't return anything for `request.readyState === 4`. So the preloader won't hide when the result is displayed

Comment: i did `console.log(request.readyState);` and the entire time it only gives the result `1`

Comment: I changed the answer to include request.onreadystatechange function which I forgot earlier.

Comment: Another way would be to put `preloader.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');` inside the block that executes when status === 200 and whatever checks you did tells you that the request completed successfully. That's what I like about programming, there's always more than one way to achieve something.

Comment: your answer worked. thank you very much. much appreciated